# Chrome seems to be throwing an 'unsafe website' warning on any SE page I open

Tags: support, google-chrome

I was working away this morning, and checked my browser, and discovered the three tabs I'd opened on space.stackexchange all had switched to this warning message, which seems to come from Google themselves.

[image]
[image]

I am waiting to see if the problem reappears. I have no idea if I'm looking at a virus on my end, or what. In case it might have something to do with an attack on Stack Exchange, I wanted to let you know.

Comment: Are you sure your browser/pc/network isn't compromised? I can't repro for space.se or chat.se

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm just asking myself what to do about it. At the moment I'm sending a report to Google that it's a false positive.

Comment: Do you have the Better History extension? (top Google result for "unanalytics.com" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232766/1990216)

Comment: @Cai Oh! Thanks, that's very helpful. But no, I never had that extension. I'm going to try an ad blocker. Or maybe switch to Firefox for now....

Comment: Try disabling **all** your browser extensions, and see if that works. If it does, enable them one-by-one and report back to us which extension was causing the problem.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Ok. At the moment I'm using Firefox because the issue makes me twitchy and I'm not sure it's a good idea for me to be using Chrome at all. But i'll load a couple of safe pages and try to test like you say.

Comment: Oh - look at that - i did have Better History and don't remember doing that at all. I've disabled it. As that has worked for others, i'm going to let it sit with space.se open and see if it happens again.

Comment: Better post it as answer. /cc @Cai

Answer (score 8):

The Better History Extension for Chrome was at fault, it very much seems. Reopening Chrome and opening space.stackexchange caused the issue to happen again, though there is a delay of about 15 or 20 minutes. Now with it disabled, it has been a couple of hours and it hasn't happened.

The issue has been raised and answered on SuperUser now as well - [Deceptive site ahead: unanalytics.com](https://superuser.com/q/1320836/510289).

Comment: Looks like developer sold the extension and it ended up [*going rogue, hijacking browsers and displaying ads*](https://hotforsecurity.bitdefender.com/blog/better-history-chrome-extension-goes-rogue-hijacks-browsers-and-displays-ads-13674.html)

Comment: @brasofilo and this only makes me happy that I don't use browser extension/plugins. I consider all of them as malware to begin with.